# Should I auto run update un ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, cron

a new weeks ago, I had to re-install my system because my OS was out up date. I think I did not take system update seriously and end up loose some of my config. I am asking myself few questions.

1. Should I auto update my OS (For example add a crontab that simple
   does `sudo apt update` regularly)
2. Should I do the same for (`sudo apt upgrade`  )
3. How to make sure I don't miss update again (I know the major update
   is in 4 years)

Thanks

Comment: Providing release details maybe helpful; eg. major update in 4 years??  A standard release is EOL in just 9 months, LTS or *long-term-support* releases are 3 of 5 years (depending on which you install; *flavors* & `universe` repository are 3 years, where as `main` Ubuntu repository is 5 years).  Also note `sudo apt upgrade` may not perform all upgrades; `apt- full-upgrade` exists for that purposes (read the `man` pages)

Comment: Ubuntu and official derivatives all check updates automatically, and prompt the user to install them. Not sure what "my OS" is, evidently, it's not Ubuntu.